# python write data from the list to a CSV a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on below code to write a list of data to a CSV file with python
I am using below code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ("input.csv")
#From column name Test2 take count value of entry which is simple
simp = df.Test2.value_counts().Simple
list1 = [2, 5, 3, 3, 3]
#multiplying the above list value with the count of simple from input CSV
simplelist = [i * simp for i in list1]
print(simplelist)
# till here its working. Its printing as expected [24, 60, 36, 36, 36]
# I need to write the CSV with above value 1 to 5 from above list with Type as Simple
df1 = pd.DataFrame[(simplelist)]
index=['Simple', '0']
columns=['Type', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5']
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Above code is failing, request you to help to address the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create list with `+` for join and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
simplelist = [24, 60, 36, 36, 36]

columns=['Type', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Simple'] + simplelist], columns=columns)

print (df1)
     Type  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
0  Simple      24      60      36      36      36
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the  `index` and `column` variable anywhere in the script.

Just define the `index` and `column` lists where you create the `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ("input.csv")
#From column name Test2 take count value of entry which is simple
simp = df.Test2.value_counts().Simple
list1 = [2, 5, 3, 3, 3]
#multiplying the above list value with the count of simple from input CSV
simplelist = [i * simp for i in list1]
print(simplelist)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(simplelist, index=['Simple', '0'], columns=['Type', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5'])
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```